# exc_bad_access (code=2, address=0x27) in uisearchbar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisearchbar

I'm new in iPhone, I created a SearchViewController like in this link: 
[UISearchBar](http://zaldzbugz.posterous.com/how-to-search-a-string-inside-uiwebview)
But when I press the SearchBar in gives me the following Error:
    EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x27)
in main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
     //in this line it gives me the error
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MFAppDelegate class])); 

}
}
```

Any Help in this issue?

Comment: Can you post the error message in your console and the related code? The main.m file doesn't really help.

Comment: it gives me the following: message sent to deallocated instance 0x90a39a0 what is this mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the class the member of is deallocated you can enable ZombieMode, together with the backtrace that will help you to understand where you have the memory management error.

Comment: I enabled Zombie object and it gives me the following: message sent to deallocated instance 0x90a39a0
what is this mean ?

Comment: @user1553381 try to follow this: http://coderslike.us/2009/05/05/finding-freeddeallocated-instances-of-objects/